# Inserting into bigquery using go updates / overwrites instead of inserts

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I have an aws lambda written in Go that should insert into bigquery.
It reference the cloud.google.com/go/bigquery package.

```
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID, gcpOption)
if err != nil {
    println(fmt.Sprintf("error creating new client, %v", err))
    return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.NewClient: %v", err)
}
defer client.Close()

inserter := client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID).Inserter()
if err := inserter.Put(ctx, items); err != nil {
    println(fmt.Sprintf("error inserting, %v", err))
    if multiError, ok := err.(bigquery.PutMultiError); ok {
        for _, err1 := range multiError {
            for _, err2 := range err1.Errors {
                fmt.Println(err2)
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return err
} else {
    println("Inserted record")
}
```

When run, a record will be inserted, but running again will result in the previously inserted row being updated. This is not the behaviour I was expecting.
I am relatively new to Golang and GCP, so perhaps I have the wrong expectations?

The table in big query is not partitioned.
Items is an array of structs.

Answer (score 1):

The `Inserter` can be used to achieve at-least-once data insertion semantics. The insert mechanism is not capable of upsert behavior, which is what you appear to be describing.

It's unclear to me how you're validating this behavior, but I'd take another look at that as a starting point.

More information about the `tabledata.insertAll` streaming API which underlies the go `Inserter` can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have been testing this by logging into the GCP console and querying the bigquery table; select * and also select count

Comment: Is it possible that I am triggering the dedupe behaviour unexpectedly somehow?

Comment: For compatibility reasons, the default behavior of the `Inserter` is to use dedupe ids for the rows even when one isn't supplied. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows#bigquery_table_insert_rows-go for an example of a saver that uses the `NoDedupeID` sentinel value.